# Ethernet stack for ROS

Tags: ros, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a micro controller with TCP/IP and Ethernet stack available, This is capable of sending the messages over TCP/IP. But is there any possibility with ROS to receive these message with a Linux PC running ROS.

A similar package to rosserial or something..?

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196871/ethernet-stack-for-ros/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, [rosserial_server](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_server) exists for this purpose. We use it regularly to send information from Windows programs to ROS (example use cases: Microsoft Kinect 2 SDKs, Thalmic Myo SDK). Another option is [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-11-13**:
See also rosserial_embedded_linux -- this is the client library for C/C++ devices that lack support for Boost.